# How to delete all contents of local Artifactory repository via REST API?

Tags: artifactory

I'm using a local repository as a staging repo and would like to be able to clear the whole staging repo via REST. How can I delete the contents of the repo without deleting the repo itself?

Comment: This does not exactly answers your question, but the following JFrog CLI command deletes all the files in a repository: jfrog rt del repo-name

Answer (score 0):

Since I have a similar requirement in one of my environments I like to provide a possible solution approach.

It is assumed the JFrog Artifactory instance has a local repository called `JFROG-ARTIFACTORY` which holds the latest JFrog Artifactory Pro installation RPM(s). For listing and deleting I've created the following script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash

# The logged in user will be also the admin account for Artifactory REST API

A_ACCOUNT=$(who am i | cut -d " " -f 1)

LOCAL_REPO=$1
PASSWORD=$2
STAGE=$3
URL="example.com"

# Check if a stage were provided, if not set it to PROD

if [ -z "$STAGE" ]; then
    STAGE="repository-prod"
fi

# Going to list all files within the local repository
# Doc: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-FileList

curl --silent \
     -u"${A_ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" \
     -i \
     -X GET "https://${STAGE}.${URL}/artifactory/api/storage/${LOCAL_REPO}/?list&deep=1" \
     -w "\n\n%{http_code}\n"
echo

# Going to delete all files in the local repository
# Doc: https://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/JFROG/Artifactory+REST+API#ArtifactoryRESTAPI-DeleteItem

curl --silent \
     -u"${A_ACCOUNT}:${PASSWORD}" \
     -i \
     -X DELETE "https://${STAGE}.${URL}/artifactory/${LOCAL_REPO}/" \
     -w "\n\n%{http_code}\n"
echo
```

So after calling

```bash
./Scripts/deleteRepository.sh JFROG-ARTIFACTORY Pa\$\$w0rd! repository-dev
```

for the development instance, it listed me all files in the local repository called `JFROG-ARTIFACTORY`, the JFrog Artifactory Pro installation RPM(s), deleted them, but left the local repository itself.

You may change and enhance the script for your needs and have also a look into [How can I completely remove artifacts from Artifactory?](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/how-can-i-completely-remove-artifacts-from-artifactory/)